# downgrade naoqi's version on Pepper

Tags: pepper

since the update with naoqi 2.5.5, I have some problems with the speech recognition and with some python programms which doesn't run normally.
Is anyone try to downgrade the naoqi image please?
If yes, could you give me the link where downloaded the old version of naoqi please? (I've didn't save my bot's configuration before the update).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that speech recognition is hard to use properly, you may want to use ALDialog instead, it does the same things but works much better.

Comment: The speech recognition works fine before the update. That's why I want to downgrade quickly because I have to show the robot and one application in two days.

Comment: It's always dangerous to upgrade before a demonstration... what was the version you use before?

Comment: The problem has been resolved. It's just some APIs who didn't work fine with the new version. Thanks to everyone who answered me.